# How can I make Manipulate faster?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, manipulate

I'm happy with the result of the graph I made, but it runs very slowly. How can I make it lighter and faster?

```
f[x_] = c;
g[x_] = -3 x^3 + 2 x;
sol[c_] := Solve[{g[x] == c, 0 < x < Sqrt[2/3]}, x];
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[{c, g[x]}, {x, 0, Sqrt[2/3]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 
      Sqrt[2/3] + 0.1}, {-0.1, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"f(x)=c", 
     "g(x)=-3\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\)+2x"}, 
   Epilog -> {{Blue, PointSize@Large, 
      Text[Style["A", Black], {-0.02 + x /. sol[c][[1]], c + 0.02}], 
      Point[{x /. sol[c][[1]], c}]}, {Red, PointSize@Large, 
      Text[Style["B", Black], {0.02 + x /. sol[c][[2]], c + 0.02}], 
      Point[{x /. sol[c][[2]], c}]}}], 
  Plot[{c, g[x]}, {x, 0, x /. sol[c][[1]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 
      Sqrt[2/3] + 0.1}, {-0.1, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Blue}}}], 
  Plot[{c, g[x]}, {x, x /. sol[c][[1]], x /. sol[c][[2]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 
      Sqrt[2/3] + 0.1}, {-0.1, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red}}}]], {{c, 
   4/9 + 0.001, "c="}, 0, (4 Sqrt[2])/9, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
 Button["Reset", c = 4/9 + 0.001]]
```

[image: Blue and Red areas are equal]

Comment: Try adding `ContinuousAction -> False, TrackedSymbols :> {c}` at the end and see if this helps. `ContinuousAction -> False` tells it not to evaluate until you release the mouse which speeds it up,

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Instead of solving the equation each time you change $c$, you can solve it once beforehand (because it has a closed-form solution): `sol = Solve[g[x] == c, x, Reals]`. Afterwards, use this result and filter out the solution that is inside your desired range ($0<x<\sqrt{2/3}$).

Answer (score 9):

You can use a single `Plot` function and add the required annotations using the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and  [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) as follows:

First, option combination `MeshFunctions -> {g[#] &}` and `Mesh -> {{c}}` identifies the solutions to `g[x] == c` without the need for `Solve` and subsequent replacements.

Next, we use an undocumented *feature* that allows using functions as the option setting for `MeshStyle` to add desired styling and labels to mesh points:

```
meshStyle = {AbsolutePointSize[10], 
    ReplaceAll[Point[{a_, b_}] :> 
     {Blue, Point @ a, Text["A", a, {1, -2}], 
      Red, Point @ b, Text["B", b, {-1, -2}]}] @ #} &;
```

Then, just add the option `MeshStyle -> meshStyle` to `Plot` to get desired annotations:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{c, g[x]}, {x, 0, Sqrt[2/3]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.1, Sqrt[2/3] + 0.1}, {-0.1, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1}},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"f(x)=c", 
    "g(x)=-3\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\)+2x"}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> {c, {Blue, Red}}},
  MeshFunctions -> {g[#] &}, 
  Mesh -> {{c}}, 
  MeshStyle -> meshStyle, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  DisplayFunction -> ReplaceAll[{p_Polygon, _Polygon} :> p]], 
 {{c, 4/9 + 0.001, "c="}, 0, (4 Sqrt[2])/9, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
 Button["Reset", c = 4/9 + 0.001]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Speed principle: Recalculate with each update only those things that need recalculating.

How vigorously to pursue this goals should be moderated by another principle: If `Manipulate` is responsive enough, then the code is fast enough.

This "lesson" pursues the first principle vigorously and pretty much ignores the second one. The purpose of the example code below is to illustrate what can be done and what it might cost. For instance, base plots do not usually need to be updated and the elements that need updating can be recalculated separately.  But `Plot[]` is usually fast enough and recalculating the base plot is usually acceptable. Below we ignore this and calculate the base plot separately. This costs us the convenience of `Filling`, since the filling needs to be recalculated each time `c` is changed. The cost is some programming — easy programming (for me) but time and testing (for me and anyone else). `Solve[]` also needs calculating only once. Like `Plot[]`, `Solve[]` is often fast enough, and it is here. The actual slowdown in the OP's code is the result of calling `Solve[]` and `Plot[]` so many times. Every `sol[c]` calls `Solve[]` to repeat its calculation. Below we call `Solve[]` once in the initialization, and use the result repeated. Its one of the few times that using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` is useful in defining a function.

```
f[x_] = c;
g[x_] = -3 x^3 + 2 x;

Manipulate[
 With[{
   (* split graph into blue, red segments *)
   lines = SplitBy[graph, Sign[Last[#] - c] &],
   xint = sol[c]},
  Show[
   Graphics[{ (* put shading under graph *)
     Blue, Polygon[Join[{{xint[[1]], c}, {0., c}}, lines[[1]]]],
     Red, 
     Polygon[Join[{{xint[[2]], c}, {xint[[1]], c}}, lines[[2]]]],
     AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Line[{{0, c}, {Sqrt[2/3], c}}]
     }]
   , plot
   , Graphics[{ (* put intersection points on top of graph *)
     {Blue, PointSize@Large,
      Text[Style["A", Black], {xint[[1]], c}, {1.5, -1.5}],
      Point[{xint[[1]], c}]},
     {Red, PointSize@Large,
      Text[Style["B", Black], {xint[[2]], c}, {-1.5, -1.5}],
      Point[{xint[[2]], c}]}}]
   , Axes -> True
   , PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 
      Sqrt[2/3] + 0.1}, {-0.1, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1}}
   ]
  ]
 , {{c, 4/9 + 0.001, "c="}, 0.001, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 - 0.00001, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}
 , {{plot, plot}, None}
 , {{graph, graph}, None}
 , {{sol, sol}, None}
 , Button["Reset", c = 4/9 + 0.001]
 , Initialization :> (
   plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, Sqrt[2/3]},
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
     (* alternative form for legend: *)
     PlotLegends -> {HoldForm[f[x]] == f[x], 
       HoldForm[g[x]] == g[x]}];
   (* two Line[] objects, one for f and one for g: *)
   graph = Last@Cases[Normal@plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];
   sol[g0_] = 
    Flatten@Normal@
      SolveValues[{g[x] == g0, 0 <= x < Sqrt[2/3], 
        0 < g0 < MaxValue[{g[x], 0 < x < Sqrt[2/3]}, x]}, {x}])
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it runs very nicely. I don't understand exactly what you did but I'll sit down and study it.

Answer (score 5):

- Not the fully answer,only remove the right blue part.

```
g[x_] = -3 x^3 + 2 x;
Manipulate[
 Block[{plot = 
    Plot[{c, g[x]}, {x, 0, Sqrt[2/3]}, 
     Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red, Blue}}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]},
  Delete[plot, Position[plot, Polygon[{_}]] // Last]], {c, .01, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`"]

f[x_] = c;

g[x_] = -3 x^3 + 2 x;

sol[c_] = Solve[{g[x] == c, 0 < x < Sqrt[2/3]}, x, Reals];
```

[`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{x1 = x /. sol[c][[1]], x2 = x /. sol[c][[2]]},
  Show[
   Plot[{ConditionalExpression[c, x <= x2], g[x],
     ConditionalExpression[c, x > x2]},
    {x, 0, Sqrt[2/3]},
    PlotRange -> {-0.03, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1},
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
    Filling -> 2 -> {1},
    FillingStyle -> {LightBlue, LightRed},
    PlotLegends -> (StringForm["``\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", #, 
         ReleaseHold[#]] & /@
       {HoldForm[f[x]], HoldForm[g[x]]}),
    Epilog -> {
      Text[#[[1]], {#[[2]], c}, 
         1.5 {Sign[Sqrt[2]/3 - #[[2]]], -1}] & /@
       {{"A", x1}, {"B", x2}},
      PointSize@Large,
      {Blue, Point[{x1, c}]},
      {Red, Point[{x2, c}]}}]]],
 {{c, Round[4/9, 0.001], "c\[ThickSpace]=\[ThinSpace]"}, 0.001, 
  Floor[4 Sqrt[2]/9, 0.001],
  0.001, Appearance -> {"Open", "Labeled"}},
 Button["Reset", c = Round[4/9, 0.001]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to reduce continuous manipulation evalution is to dicretize the parameter to some 20 values, enough for visualisation as - known from cinema - by a With statement with a step function

```
  With[{c = Floor[20 cf]/20},.... 

f[x_] = c;
g[x_] = -3 x^3 + 2 x;
sol[c_] := Solve[{g[x] == c, 0 < x < Sqrt[2/3]}, x];
Manipulate[
 With[{c = Floor[20 cf]/20}, 
  Show[Plot[{c, g[x]}, {x, 0, Sqrt[2/3]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 
       Sqrt[2/3] + 0.1}, {-0.1, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"f(x)=c", 
      "g(x)=-3\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\)]\)+2x"}, 
    Epilog -> {{Blue, PointSize@Large, 
       Text[Style["A", Black], {-0.02 + x /. sol[c][[1]], c + 0.02}], 
       Point[{x /. sol[c][[1]], c}]}, {Red, PointSize@Large, 
       Text[Style["B", Black], {0.02 + x /. sol[c][[2]], c + 0.02}], 
       Point[{x /. sol[c][[2]], c}]}}], 
   Plot[{c, g[x]}, {x, 0, x /. sol[c][[1]]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 
       Sqrt[2/3] + 0.1}, {-0.1, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Blue}}}], 
   Plot[{c, g[x]}, {x, x /. sol[c][[1]], x /. sol[c][[2]]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 
       Sqrt[2/3] + 0.1}, {-0.1, (4 Sqrt[2])/9 + 0.1}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red}}}]]], {{cf,
    4/9 + 0.001, "c="}, 0, (4 Sqrt[2])/9, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
 Button["Reset", cf = 4/9 + 0.001]]
```